# rationale of するんじゃない as informal negative imperative

Tags: grammar, etymology, expressions, colloquial-language

I know verb-んじゃない can be used in colloquial speech as a negative imperative (e.g. するんじゃない) in lieu of verb-な (するな), but why exactly does it function that way?
That is, what is the rationale/etymology behind v-んじゃない being a negative imperative?

Comment: FWIT, the の is not compulsory.

Comment: @oldergod, I would say that it is for this meaning, at least in Standard Japanese.

Comment: @dainichi I have seen it missing many times for the negative command, as broccoli, kindly confirms.

Comment: @oldergod, ~でない without の is fine, ~じゃない without の is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously it's not grammatical imperative, but the construction *functions* as order when used by somebody's betters (senior, superior etc.) to strongly admonish them. If I can ignore context, "You don't want to do —!" could be a way of translation.

- V(する)-んだ！ (more pompously V(する)-のだ！): affirmative command
- V(する)-んじゃない！ (V(する)-のではない！, V(する)-でない！): negative command

Incidentally, the dictionary form is also employed as command, with colloquial but very overbearing tone.

- V(する)！: affirmative
- V(し)-ない！: negative

Comment: Rather than "You don't want to do...", I think maybe "You aren't ..." is a more literal translation of this.